# No Sound in Kali Linux 2021.4 on [ASUS TUF B560M Plus]

Tags: linux, kali-linux, sound-card, alsa, pulse-audio

Hello I fresh installed Kali linux 2021.4 but it has no sound, [It was working on Windows]

However I tried some stuff suggested by community:
Added Following Lines in `.bashrc`

```
pulseaudio -D
clear
```

After rebooting it did show system audio instead of dummy output but there was no sound and upon manually trying to select different sound port i.e. `Built in HDMI Sound` It switched back to dummy Audio.

I also tried to add `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`

Still no sound

I tried completely removing pulseaudio reinstalled

No luck

Here is a screenshot of all the solutions on internet i tried had no luck in one screenshot
`Alsa Mixer Showing all sounds to MAX and HDA Intel PCH is enabled`
In settings
`Digital Output is selected`
Yet it shows Dummy output when I try to increase or decrease the Volume
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r13D6.jpg)

Comment: If you are trying to use Kali as a general-purpose desktop distro, you are doing it wrong. Read their FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, you need to install pipewire-pulse

```
sudo apt install pipewire-pulse
```

Then restart, and it should work

For some reason it is installed in the live image and thus it works there, but it doesn't when you manually install it or download the rebuilt VM